# Why does the Alpha Over node make my image brighter?

Tags: compositing-nodes

In a Cycles project in Blender 2.9, I want all objects to receive white light from the environment, so I set World Properties --> Surface --> Color to white.

But I want the background of the final result to be dark blue, so I checked Render Properties --> Film --> Transparent, and use an Alpha Over node in the compositor to get my blue background.

This is the original rendered image with a transparent background:
[image]

And this is the picture with the blue background composited in:
[image]

As you can see, the Alpha Over mode makes the image much brighter. But I don't want that: I just want the original image with a blue background.

What I tried:

1. Checking "Convert Premul" (should not be needed, because the rendered image already contains a premultiplied alpha channel)
2. Manually changing "Fac" (which has an unexpected behaviour: it takes an extremely low value (0.0001) to make the foreground transparent. I expected the foreground to be 50% transparent at Fac = 0.5)
3. Connect the Alpha output of the Render Layers node to the Fac input of the Alpha Over node (should not be needed, because the alpha channel should already be in the picture itself)
4. Setting the brightness of the Sun lamp that is also in my scene, to 0.
   All of this did not solve my problem.

My question: How do I get the rendered image in front of a blue background, without making the rendered image brighter?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do to reduce the overblown brightness in the semi-transparent parts is using the *Alpha Convert Node* in the *Compositor*. Put it between the *Render Layers* and the *Alpha Over* and set it to "Straight to Premul". This reduces the brightness in transparent areas a lot.

The transparency in the render still won't look like the transparency in the *Viewer Node*.

To get that result you need to clamp the image's RGB values, for example by using a *Color > Mix* node with *Clamp* enabled. Then you can multiply the image with pure white or add pure black and then the output has all bright pixels clamped to white and the alpha transparency works on that. The thing is, if you want that, why is the brightness so high anyway?

Although you said, you set the strength of the *Sun Lamp* to 0 and even that didn't change much, the file you provided had a sun with a strength of 1000. In Blender, a sun even with only a strength of 10 is very bright.

So rendering your file with the cube and a sun of 1000 resulted in semi-transparent areas around the cube, which had RGB values above 150 or even 200 at a transparency of 60%-80%, which gives pixels far beyond white. And that's why everything is so much more bright then in the Backdrop view.

You should set the sun way lower to get the result you want. If your objects look grey instead of white and that's why you cranked up the sun value, try setting *View Transform > Standard* instead of *Filmic* in the *Color Management*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I simplified the scene to only 1 cube. You can find the blend-file here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/da5tym8hl4ur38g/Alpha_over_node_makes_objects_far_from_camera_brighter.blend/file
I found out that the issue happens when an object is far away from the camera, and only consists of a few pixels in the render. But why? The compositor doesn't know that this is an objects far away. It should only see the individual pixels, and treat them all the same way, right?

Comment: I tried your alternative solution, bit it had exactly the same result (as least, visually) as the Alpha Over node solution.
In both solutions, pixels near the border between opaque and transparent pixels are made brighter.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow when I'm at the right computer. I already feared it might happen with my workaround, too. Anyway, maybe we can find it out.

Comment: You wrote in the question, you've set the _Sun Lamp_ to 0 and it didn't change anything. I've downloaded the file and at least there the sun has a strength of 1000 - for a sun lamp as light source even 10 is already a high value. Especially when the _World_ is already lightening up the scene with white color at a strength of 1. After rendering, right-clicking the cube results in RGB values above 200, which means even in the half-transparent borders they are far above 1. The white of the cube is fully blown. It got a little bit better when I've set the _Premul_ slider to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make the sun less bright.

Comment: But can you explain why the superbright pixels (way beyond white) become even brighter by using the Alpha Over node? And is there a way to turn the superbright pixels into normal RGB values before performing the Alpha Over? I thought the Filmic "filter" is applied at the end of the node chain, not at the start. So the input of the Alpha Over node would still be ultrabright.

Comment: They don't become brighter. It's the _Image Editor_ not capable of showing them correctly. If you render the image and leave the background transparent, they are shown clipped to white at 1 and then multiplied with the alpha value which makes them less then 1 in semi-transparent areas. But if you right-click some of these pixels, the RGB values are still displayed as beyond white. When you put a background behind them, Blender calculates the "real" mix values. So, e.g. a value of 0.1 at 100% opacity overplayed by 60% opacity of 150 is 0.1 + 90 = 90.1, which is clipped to 1 at 100% opacity.

Comment: The _Filmic_ transfirm is not applied at the start, and it doesn't make the pixels brighter. Since it has wider dynamic range, values must go beyond white to not appear light grey. I just mentioned because I was wondering why would someone crank up the sun to 1000? What you could do get the image less bright: make the sun much darker or even delete it. Or if it has to be like that, reduce the color range.

Comment: For example, plug the image into a _Seperate RGBA_ node,  plug the R, G and B each into a _Map Range_ node with _Output Min/Max_ set to 0/1. Set _Input Min_ to 0 and _Input Max_ to 5 or what looks good. Then _Combine RGBA_ and plug the image output into the second socket of a _Color > Mix RGB_ node with dark blue as the first color. Use the _Alpha Channel_ as the Mix Factor.

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot again.

Comment: I've edited the answer (again) because I completely forgot about the _Alpha Convert Node_. With that, some of the overpowering white gets reduced, but it's still not the same as the Backdrop in the Compositor. To (more or less) achieve that look, I've provided a clamp method as well. But all this results in reducing the brightness as you could have done before rendering.

Comment: Thanks for all your research / explanation. It's hard to understand how colors work in Blender, but it has become a little more clear for me. I guess the best solution for this particular problem is to give the sun lamp a normal strength.

Comment: You should never ever clamp values if you are using filmic (it kind of defeats the entire purpose of using a scene referred transformas that what a display referred transform is doing, clamping 0-1). Use the CDL node at the end of the node tree to correct the output with false color if needed to pull the blown out areas back to middle gray/ cyan. Your renders will be much better off.

Comment: @Timaroberts Of course you shouldn't clamp. It's just he was going to achieve the look of the Compositor Backdrop in the Render Result... and that's how you get it. Why he started out with such overly bright light in the first place I don't know, because for that result he might have gotten away with just the world lightening the scene.

Comment: Gordon, in one of your earlier answers you described an interesting alternative using a world light with colour x, but a background with color y (without using the compositor).
Unfortunately, I can't remember how you did it, and you deleted this solution from your answer. Where can I find the setting for the background color again?

Comment: Oh wait... it had something to do with the World Shader, and handling camera rays differently than non-camera rays... I think I can figure it out myself

Comment: You're right, that's it. Use the _Is Camera Ray_ output of the _Light Path_ node for mix factor.